# UK - Money Claim Online for Non-Resident

Tags: united-kingdom, non-resident, debt-collection

My (non-UK) client (UK) hasn't paid me for over 2 years now. We connected via famous freelancing platform, but they don't help. There's no debate over my right in the money, but back then when I had the money to hire a solicitor, I didn't want to force this and was hoping for a settlement, but I only received excuses.

Every pay-after-settlement debt collector I reached out needed her address, which was hidden across the whole web, she used Virtual Addresses everywhere.

Came by Gov.uk's 'Money Claim Online' but they require her address to process with the case, contacted the county she lives at and they require a court action to give her address! contacted the freelancing platform that should've added her address to all the invoices but they require a court action too.

Currently, I'm pennyless and still recovering from a severe mental illness and have no clue what to do, or should I give up?

Comment: why have you been working for 2 years without payment?

Comment: Is it a company you've been freelancing for, or an individual?

Comment: @user253751 the unpaid invoices are for ~3 months, but the money wasn't paid for 2 years now.. actually I like to work on a human-to-human basis; I do care for personal matters, biz matters and for sure pandemic matters. 

I've achieved nothing but good reputation working with such mindset, until I was shocked that some people do not appreciate sympathy.

Comment: @marktristan the invoices are for both a personal brand & a biz brand (established ltd in UK).

Comment: I suppose the lesson here is to find the real-world identity of your clients. If you have enough money to go through a court case you might be able to get the freelancing site (or somewhere else, e.g. email provider) subpoenad to find out who the user is. Maybe you can enter "unknown address" in the money claim thing and proceed - I have no idea whether that can work, but the worst they can do is say no, come back when you know the address. (I doubt you'd be penalized, as penalties generally happen to people who *lie*)

Comment: @user253751 Thank you, this was really helpful. Any idea whether it is possible to deduct the claim fees after the claim or not? I remember there's some sort of financial aid form there but I'm not sure if non-residents are eligable.

Comment: absolutely no idea sorry

Answer (score 2):

Even if you win a case via Money Claim Online - which is just an alternative way of getting a court case started - you don't automatically get the money. You would still need to use debt collectors or court bailiffs to enforce the judgement.

They might have a slightly larger incentive to pay up, particularly if they are an individual, as the judgement would be a public record others would see and would affect getting credit. But you shouldn't see winning a case with Money Claim Online as the entire solution.

If you can't find a way of getting their address then sadly I think I would give up at this point.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps.

what do you think is the best route to take?

Comment: @OldEgyptian I can't see any realistic route to actually getting the money if you don't know the address. (And maybe not even then - collecting debts is not easy.)